# How can i increase speed of m wordpress movie site

Tags: wordpress, performance

Hello everbody i have a 2 sites for movies and want to make them load faster since they are movie sites there are tons of pics in them and they need to get optimized i use a few plugins for speeding up which are wp smush, wp super cache, auto optimize - i was using wp minify and wp optimize too but disabled them...
cloudflare confiuration made like that in the link https://onlinemediamasters.com/wp-super-cache-settings/

so can you give me good wordpress plugin combination to faster up my site please

my site links cartoonmovieswatch,online watchmoviesonlinefree,stream

my page speed results below from 2 known sites

[B]GMETRIX [/B]

https://prnt.sc/mz0mkn

[B]GOOGLE SPEED TEST[/B]

https://prnt.sc/mz0mv4

https://prnt.sc/mz0mww

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Unfortunately your question is a bit vague and I can't see an actual coding problem.

Comment: just want to increase speed of page load, and fix the errors which given by speed test tools as u can see from SS, so what is exactly that you didint understand